# SDL2 unable to unlock surface

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have been writing some SDL2 lately and today i rewrote the base of my code to make it more structured and easier to use.

The issue i am having is when trying to blit the sprites surface, there it gives me the SDL error `Surfaces must not be locked during blit` which seemed reasonable so i added `SDL_UnlockSurface` to the beginning of my blit function before `SDL_BlitSurface` but still returned the same error.
Since i saw in the documentation that `SDL_UnlockSurface` is a void, i cannot know if it was successful or not, but since it's not multi-threaded nothing can force lock it while i'm blitting (and it's only drawing to the surface at the start of the application anyway).

Here's the blit function

```
bool Sprite::blit(SDL_Surface* targetSurface){
    SDL_UnlockSurface(this->surface);
    int success = SDL_BlitSurface( this->surface, NULL, targetSurface, NULL );
    if ( success != 0){
        printf( "Unable to blit surface! SDL Error: %s\n"m SDL_GetError() );
        return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locks are counted. If you locked surface twice, you have to unlock it twice. Better avoid this scheme - the same function that locked surface should unlock it after its job is done.

You can look at `surface->locked` variable, which is locks count, but it isn't included in documentation so you can't rely on this name - it could be changed in future versions.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, didn't know that. What still doesn't make sense is that i unlock it every frame and i have never written anywhere in the code that it should have been locked in the first place. I am only using a single sprite in the whole application and its surface is only drawn to once with SDL_LoadBMP, and it returns that it was successful so it doesn't really fix the problem

Comment: I just checked the lock count, and the lock count is very high.
What's wierd is that the lock count jumps from 512 to 1024 when the application is focused and jumps back to 512 when unfocused, what could possibly change that?

This is the correct answer though, i just have to dig deeper into my code, thanks!

Comment: All I could recommend is running in debugger and setting breakpoint in LockSurface. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with SDL2 drawing - was using SDL 1.2 for quite a time, then switched to opengl drawing. SDL2 focusing more on textures and renderer, perhaps it is forbidden to blit directly onto screen surface.